# „Ebenfalls ein Argument für die Notengebung(,) ist der […] Ansporn …“

Tags: punctuation, comma

In dem folgenden Satz:

> Ebenfalls ein Argument für die Notengebung ist der daraus resultierende Ansporn, sich näher mit den Themen des jeweiligen Fachs auseinanderzusetzen.

Wird hier ein Komma zwischen *Notengebung* und *ist* benötigt? Wenn ja, warum? Wenn nein, geht es überhaupt und welcher Grammatikregel folgt das? (Den oben stehenden Satz habe ich so in meinem Deutschaufsatz – einer Argumentation – geschrieben und darauf einen Fehler auf Zeichensetzung bekommen.)

Comment: P.S.: Ich bin Muttersprachler, lasst euch dadurch aber nicht aufhalten, mich zu verbessern.

Comment: Nein, da kommt im Deutschen kein Komma hin. Im Englischen werden solche Zusätze wie "However, ..." oder "That said, ..." mit einem Komma abgetrennt, aber im Deutschen nicht. Stell den Satz um: "Der ... Ansporn ist ebenfalls ein Argument..." --- da sähe ein Komma nach "ist" noch falscher aus.

Comment: @Robert Gut, dann liegt meine Deutschlehrerin falsch.

Comment: @palsch Sie mag *noch* Unrecht haben, aber der Sprachwandel bewegt sich eindeutig in Richtung "Vorfeldmarkierung durch Komma". Tageszeitungen schreiben immer öfter "Nach langen Verhandlungen bei der Friedenskonferenz, wurde am Montag berichtet..." Nur wenn das Vorfeld auch noch topikalisiert ist wie hier, ist das Komma noch völlig abwegig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Kommaregeln finden sich in §§ 71 mit 79 der [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf). Sie lassen sich zusammenfassen als:

- § 71: Zwischen gleichrangige Sätze, Wörter oder Wortgruppen gehört ein Komma
- § 72: Kein Komma vor *und* oder ähnlichen Wörtern
- § 73: Erlaubtes Komma, wenn *und* etc. zwei gleichrangige Hauptsätze verbindet
- § 74: Nebensätze sind von paarigen Kommas zu umschließen
- § 75: Infinitivgruppen werden mit Komma abgegrenzt
- § 76: Bei formelhaften Nebensätzen braucht man kein Komma
- § 77: Zusätze oder Nachträge grenzt man mit Komma ab
- § 78: Der Schreibende kann sich aussuchen, ob etwas ein Zusatz/Nachtrag sein soll oder nicht
- § 79: Anreden, Ausrufe, etc. grenzt man durch Kommas ab

Wenn man die letzten drei Paragraphen außer Acht lässt, kann man die vereinfachte Regel aufstellen, dass ein satz(glieder)trennendes Komma immer zwischen zwei Verben stehen muss.

In deinem Beispielsatz, wie schon in einem Kommentar angedeutet, trifft nichts davon zu, es ist ein vollständiger Satz, dessen erstes Glied nun mal etwas länger ist. Wichtig ist insbesondere, dass »ebenfalls ein Argument für die Notengebung« kein Verb enthält; weder finit (Nebensatz) noch infinit (Infinitivgruppe). Daher verbietet sich ein solches Komma.